# Application running on multiple PODS

Tags: memory, kubernetes-pod

Currently my test application is running on only 1 POD(1 Replica). If I increase the Replicas then the CPU & Memory increment also required or for each POD the CPU & Memory will be allocation will be distributed based on config.

My config now.
requests:
cpu: 100m
memory: 128Mi

My doubt : If I increase PODS then for each POD the config will be 100m & 128mi or this configuration will be distributed across PODS?

Answer (score 0):

The unit suffix Mi stands for mebibytes, and so this resource object specifies that the container needs 50 Mi and can use at most 100 Mi.

```
 resources:
  requests:
    memory: 50Mi
  limits:
    memory: 100Mi
```

Resource limits are set on a per-container basis using the resources property of a containerSpec, which is a v1 api object of type ResourceRequirements.